# Determine entrys with "missing" subsequent entry in SQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table in SQL which represent some sort of events. I try to determine all lines where a specific event is not "followed" by another specific event. 
In the table below this would be all lines where somebody signed up but did not sign out afterwards (Lucy and Joe). Is this achievable with SQL and if yes how?

```
|Id|Name      |Event     |
==========================
|01|Fred      |Sign up   |
-------------------------
|02|Joe       |Sign up   |
--------------------------
|03|Lucy      |Sign up   |
--------------------------
|04|Joe       |Do foo    |
--------------------------
|05|Joe       |Sign out  |
--------------------------
|06|Joe       |Sign up   |
--------------------------
|07|Fred      |Sign out  |
--------------------------
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: Hi, I am using a MySQL DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select * from 
table as t1 left outer join table as t2
on(t1.name=t2.name and t2.event='sign out')
where
t1.event='sign up' and t2.name is null
```

There's no such thing as "followed by" unless you define it so you'll need to provide more info.  (It might be adding "t1.id >t2.id" in the ON clause)

Comment: I think we can assume that the higher id 'follows' the lower id.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM events x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN events y 
    ON y.name = x.name 
   AND y.id > x.id 
   AND y.event ='sign out' 
 WHERE x.event = 'sign up' 
   AND y.id IS NULL;
```

or something like that

Comment: Interesting - I wonder why you get 2 upvotes and I get none for providing virtually identical solutions.  Maybe I need to start taking more care over formatting :)

Comment: Life is unfair my friend.

Answer (score 1):

Closest thing I came up with was to see who has a full "Sign In" "Sign out" pair.

```
SELECT Id, Name
FROM 
    EVENTS
WHERE
     event = 'Sign up' or event = 'Sign out'
group by
    Name
having Mod(count(*), 2) <> 0
```